# select * INTO outfile generates date in wrong format

Tags: mysql, sql, date, csv

I am using the below sql to export data to a csv file:

```
select * INTO outfile 'customer.csv'
    FIELDs terminated by ',' enclosed by '"'
    LINES terminated by '\n'
    from CUSTOMER customer
    where customer.date_created < '2015-10-22 10:00:00';
```

I get this result in csv:

[image]

Problem is data doesn't import from this generated csv because the date format is different than in DB.

DB date format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. Also null values are replaced with \n which also fail when importing.

How can I generate the csv columns with correct i.e. yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss date format and null/empty values?

Errors:
Incorrect datetime value: '23/07/2015 11:55' for column 'DATE_CREATED' at row 1
Incorrect integer value: '\N' for column 'column_name' at row 1

Note: 
I am using mysql workbench to import the file.
I don't want to change the format/data directly in csv file.

Thanks

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to AdrianBR I realised I was opening the file with excel first which was overriding the date format hence wrong date format was showing even with notepad++.
\n is still a problem.
When opened with notepad++ for the first time it looks like this:
"100","0","2015-12-02 10:16:36","2015-12-02 10:16:36","0",\N,

Comment: Is this MySQL or MS SQL Server? You've tagged it as both. And you've shown us what a spreadsheet program thinks is in the CSAV file - not what is *actually* there. Open it in a text editor and have a look.

Comment: " the date format is different than in DB" Databases generally store dates as binary values, without formatting. It's up to you how you format them when you display them.

Comment: it's excel, aka FTFY

Comment: @MattGibson He didn'T mention about how it is stored, but how it is displayed, and that would be ISO if comparable with that iso string.

Comment: @symcbean afaik ms sql has no into outfile, but this probably irelevant, since I am guessing his CSV is fine, like you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is most likely not coming from mysql.

It is most likely coming from the way Excel displays and later saves the dates. 
to troublehsoot:

Open the file in a text editor such as notepad or notepad++ and check what the date looks like, if it's in ISO or not. It will probably be fine.

Now, if you open it in excel, it will be displayed in local format.

If you save the file now, you are likely to overwrite the ISO date format, with excel's local date format, making it not a valid importable mysql date anymore.

Moral: don't use excel when working with data, only use it to display charts. Excel makes assumptions about your data and messes with it in the most unexpected ways. Remember than 1.19 VAT tax rate? Excel seems to think it's the same as Jan 19. That integer ID? Excel thinks it's better off to write it in scientific notation and round it to first 4 digits. That Iso date? Excel thinks you are better off guessing which is the month and which is the date. That decimal point? surely you wanted comma as decimal, and dot as thousands separator instead. FTFY!

Comment: +1 Excel was overriding the date format hence opening it in notepad++ was also showing wrong format. Date format seems to work now but the "\n" is still causing problem?

Comment: the \N is a placeholder for null. If you import the data via an excel plugin, (mysql for excel) it will be displayed properly. Otherwise, you can kind of fixing it when writing to outfile by wrapping your columns in ifnull(intcolumn, 0) or ifnull(stringcol, '')

Comment: You can also fix it in excel after opening the file by doing a replace with nothing. Keep in mind that when loading the file with \N back in mysql, it will treat it properly as nulls - so you don't actually have to mess with it

Answer (score 0):

maybe specify the columns explicitly, and include the format in the select list like so:

TO_CHAR( mydate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' )

edit:

as in:

```
SELECT my_id, my_val1, TO_CHAR( mydate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' )
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thanks, please can you elaborate? How do you specify column explicitly? I am new to this area.